# What is the use of SBC instruction in arm?

Tags: arm

I understand how the SBC instruction in ARM works.

But, I don't seem to understand how it will be **useful**, as the intended answer is always **less by 1**.

Example:

```
MOV r1, #0x88
MOV r2, #0x44
SUB r3, r1, r2
SBC r4, r1, r2
```

After this operation, r3 has 0x44 (correct) and r4 has 0x43 (incorrect).

I don't see in which case SBC is a more relevant operation than SUB.

Thanks.

Comment: just like ADC but subtraction, it is for cascading your subtraction math to be much wider.  so if I want to do a 65536 bit - 65536 bit subtraction SBC makes that take a lot fewer instructions...

Comment: (or 64 bit or 128 bit or 256 bit, or 200 bit, etc...)

Comment: do you understand how ADD/ADC work?

Comment: in your test try sub r3,r1,r2; sbc, r4,r1,r2, sub r5,r2,r1, sbc, r6,r1,r2 are r4 and r6 the same result?

Comment: you understand that 10000....00000 - 1 = 9999...99999 (decimal) yes?

Comment: and that 1000...001 - 1 = 1000...000 yes?

Comment: Thanks @old_timer. I can see how it will help my subtraction math to be wider. And i did try the code you attached. Did you mean `sbc r6, r1, r2` ?

Comment: nope was simply trying to demonstrate you will see a difference if the instruction BEFORE (the SUB) has the carry/borrow bit set vs reset.  you assumed it was always one way, but by design it uses the carry bit state from the prior carry bit change.   reversing the operands on the SUB before the SBC should change the carry bit (since you have not equal values) causing the two SBCs (with the same register order) to give two different results...

Comment: note/FYI that a subtract in logic (the beauty of twos complement assuming they are sane enough to do that) is an add.  invert and add one, so you invert the second operand change the carry in and feed it to the adder, that is a subtract. But some architectures invert the carry out and call it a borrow some dont, so as Dric512 below shows 1-CPSR.C some other non-arm architecture might feed C in unmodified into an SBC (ra - rb - C rather than ra - rb - (~C)).  The SUB C output and SBC C input would be complementary.  its when you use branch if carry after a cmp or sub that you need to know/care.

Comment: so some architectures invert second operand and carry in but dont invert carry out, some do invert carry out (for a SUB).

Comment: @old_timer, got it! In the code you sent however, I still get the same result because only `SUB` wont update the flags. `SBC` followed by `SUBS` gives us a different result as you rightly pointed out. Thanks for the clear explanation.

Comment: right, was simply echoing your code.  need to use the right instruction syntax to update flags...

Answer (score 0):

This operation is a substration that adds the carry (`PSTATE.C`) to the result:

`r4 = r1 - r2 - (1-CPSR.C)`

CPSR.NZCV has been set by a previous operation that sets flags (For example `CMP` or`ADDS`).

This type of operation can be useful for large integer additions.

For example, in Aarch32 if you want to calculate a 64-bit addition, you add the 32-bit bottom bits (`ADDS`) then use `ADDC` to do the top 32-bit with carry propagation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I can see how `SBC` instruction will help me with wider calculations!